# Have portals stopped spilling XM?

Tags: ingress

For a few days (maybe weeks?) I have been noticing that in Ingress there is no XM concentrated around portals anymore. The only way to collect XM now is to visit busy places, where it is laying around as usual.

Is it intended behavior that portals have stopped spilling XM, or is this simply a bug? Is there a official statement from Niantic regarding this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is something intended by Niantic. You can find an entire article redacted by Niantic about the matter on this [page](http://investigate.ingress.com/2016/04/03/pacs-weekly-wrap-up-april-3-2016/) :

> The current XM drought is the clear consequence of the Acolyte’s deployment of the Obsidian Shield. The technology had powers beyond what she had anticipated, and while it’s easy to cast the blame on her and the Enlightened, she was only one half of an equation: Jahan and the Resistance were pushing just as hard to meddle with this ancient force, and now we are seeing the results of their hubris and ambition.

To sum up : it's part of Ingress' story. So this is not a bug.

Comment: Any ideas how the story is likely to progress? I.e., when will we get the damn XM back? recharging my local portals eats way too many cubes at the moment …

Comment: I received a notification on my phone about three hours ago that due to (such-and-such)'s efforts, significantly more power cubes will now be available in the world.

Comment: There was a similar thing in the past when the decay rate of portals increased (the amount of energy the portal looses every day was doubled). It took an effort by both factions to stop that by building huge fields gaining many MU in a predefined time frame. In the current story there is a hint that again a shared effort of both factions will be needed. So there might be some similar goal for both factions to achieve.

Comment: The next Anomaly series is called "Aegis Nova" and will take place from 28/05/16 to 25/06/16. The XM shortage is expected to be ended after the "Aegis Nova" series.

Comment: Looks like the XM is coming back: https://fevgames.net/end-of-the-xm-drought/